# How to make upload in popup?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, upload

As in title - I have asp.net + jQuery application. I want to have a popup (jQuery UI dialog) with upload functionality. Code for my upload contains simple form with few hidden inputs, file input and a submit button - it is enough because I'm using uploadhandler (.ashx). However, I'm getting the famous "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" error and if I remove the "runat=server" attrib, upload doesn't work (pretty logical).

It's a basic question, but how to solve such problem?

Comment: Can you show us the basic code. How you make 2 forms added ? remove the form on the upload if its in the same page.

Comment: Does the popUp window have a master page reference in it?

Comment: It's a pretty standard jquery dialog included in a aspx page. The page itself has masterpage attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using webforms, then you can't get around it. There are a number of plugins which will offer you the functionality you are looking for. I assume they work by inserting an IFRAME on the page. Do a search for jquery file upload.

Comment: I think this is the best direction. Iframe with separate form. I actually implemented it now.